# User Reference For a Particular role

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 . and in a content type i created a field with user_reference,  which is working fine.

And while creating a content it shows all users.

Now i want to show  only User with particular role..

Does anybody tell me how to do this. Is there is any module avialable for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For User Reference Module, In Field settings -> already roles are defined know..  **User roles that can be referenced**

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module (rather than user reference). I would then create a view (display: entity reference) filtering only Users with that desired role.

In the field settings you can choose the designated View under "Entity Selection" - "Mode": "Views: Filter by an entity reference".

This is at least how I solved this problem in the past. I hope this helps.